# Audiosurf crashes on start up, error report refers to "languagepack.dll"

Tags: technical-issues, windows-xp, audiosurf

I got Audiosurf on Steam about a month ago, which I was able to run perfectly. Then, I had to re-install Windows, and since then I could not start up the game at all.

Well, technically, it does start, but after a couple of seconds, it instantly crashes.

I contacted the developer, but he couldn't give me much help. I tried (**re**)installing:

- Microsoft XNA Framework Redistributable 4.0
- Microsoft .NET Framework Redistributable 4.0
- Steam
- Audiosurf

but still nothing.

If you need any system specs, please mention which ones in the comments.

Screenshoot:
[image]

[Contents of the mentioned txt file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/rgzx953nro26tk9/35a5_appcompat.txt) *(had to link it like this because it's too long)*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many suggestions on how to fix this problem over in [this thread on the Audio Surf forums](http://www.audio-surf.com/forum/index.php?topic=5772.30) but what it seems to come down to is the following;

> Check that your filepath only has characters from A-Z and\or numbers 0-9. This fixed the problem for me.

Ensure that your Steam installation location and/or library location only contain alphanumeric characters. It is also worth noting that AudioSurf does not use CEG, so you can move the AudioSurf folder out of your steamapps folder to another location on your hard drive and run it from there.

Comment: Copying it to the root folder of my hard drive solved everything! Thanks.